# Errors after update, BigSur 11.3 XCode 12.5 (12E262) React-Native and Expo

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, updates, macos-big-sur

After upgrading BigSur to 11.3, Xcode to 12.5 and iOS to 14.5, I can't run the iOS app on a real device nor in the simulator.

React-Native -->
react-native run-ios

```
kikirim@Levent-MacBook-Pro test % react-native run-ios
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "test.xcodeproj"
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/MacOS/MacOs_Prog/Xcode-12.5.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
(node:5077) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues.
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json devices
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/MacOS/MacOs_Prog/Xcode-12.5.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:164:54)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:121:12)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:23)
    at Command.listener (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (/Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:265:24)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
kikirim@Levent-MacBook-Pro test %
```

React-Expo -->
npm run ios

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/kikirim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/text-gncpkkxvjxsnedbswzsxcynreivq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DistributedMutex.o /Users/kikirim/Desktop/React-Native/text/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is an issue with Flipper. I am not using Flipper so i just commented it out.

1. cd ios
2. comment Flipper out from podfile:

## use_flipper!()

## post_install do |installer|

## react_native_post_install(installer)

## end

3. run "pod deintegrate"
4. pod install
5. cd ..
6. npm run ios

Comment: Thanks, It worked. After updating to BigSur 11.3

Answer (score 0):

You should update react native with following these steps:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

Otherwise you will face with multiple issue.